# Ubuntu Can't Move Files to Trash with correct Ownership

Tags: permissions, delete, trash, ownership

I've already looked at the other posts and questions where the problem was a directory ownership problem where root was the owner of the directory instead of the actual user, but this is not the case with me. I am the owner of the directory and the directory has 775 for chmod permissions.

I tried deleting the Trash directory and remaking it anyways, but it didn't fix the problem. The directory is stored in `~/.local/share` (unless there's another I don't know of?)

Running Ubuntu 14 x64.

my `/home` is on the same drive as my root.

Comment: @muru my apologies, I had forgotten that I had set my desktop to store files on a NTFS partition and so the Trash wouldn't work from there. I managed to find a solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804083 Thanks anyways

Comment: Could you please post an answer describing what you did?

Comment: @muru I have posted the answer as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per muru's request, the solution I found from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804083 is as follows:

> I had the same problem and enabled the trash function for ntfs and
>   vfat partitions that are mounted by fstab as follows:
>
> 1) Backup fstab.
>
> 2) Add uid=1000,gid=1000 as options to the partition's fstab entry
>   (see example below).
>
> 3) Create a directory named .Trash-1000 in the partition's root.
>
> 4) Restart the computer.
>
> Upon completion of the above, deleted files will be placed in a
>   directory named files within the .Trash-1000 directory, and your
>   Ubuntu desktop trash icon will show the deleted files.
>
> ~~~
>
> Example fstab entry UUID=44B5-9621 /media/store vfat
>   defaults,utf8,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 1

where instad of 1000 for `gid` and `uid`, put your usernae

Please note that this is only necessary if the place that you are trying to delete from is a FAT32 or NTFS or some other partition type other than EXT4 and the likes.